# solve the Following Differential equation: $y''=2yy'$

Tags: analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Solve the following equation: $y''=2yy'$

**My attempt:**

$y''=2yy'$

integrate on both sides:

$y'=\int(2yy')$

Let y'=s

We have $\int 2y \dfrac{ds}{dy}dy = 2 \int yds = y^2$

Is that a way to integrate $2yy'$?

I fthat's the case don't we get $y=\dfrac{1}{3}y^5$ which is false

Comment: The right-hand side is $(y^2)'$.

Comment: The integral of $2\,y\,y'$ is not $2\,y^2\,y$, but $y^2+C$.

Comment: Why is that so?

Comment: It is so because you can differentiate and check. The derivative of $y^2$ is $2yy'$, while the derivative of $y^3$ is $3y^2y'$.

Comment: what is a rigorous way to prove that though?

Comment: What is non-rigourous with "We may rewrite the equation as $y''=(y^2)'$, and integration yields $y'=y^2+C$"?

Comment: yes but I'd like to know how you integrate $y^2y'$ and directly find the answer. I understand that $y^2$ is the derivative of $2yy'$ but I don't know how you found that

Comment: @aribaldi The usual substitution rule for integrals tells you that $\int f(y)y'dx=\int f(y)dy$. So integrating $2yy'$ with respect to $x$ gives the same result as integrating $2y$ with respect to $y$.

Comment: @Arthur I've edited my question: Is that a way to show it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed,

$$\frac{dy'}{dx}=2y\frac{dy}{dx}$$ 
can be integrated by

$$\int dy'=\int2y\,dy,$$

$$y'=y^2+C.$$

Then

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=y^2+c^2,$$

$$\int\frac{dy}{y^2+c^2}=dx,$$

$$\frac1c\arctan\left(\frac yc\right)=x+c',$$

$$y=c\tan(cx+c').$$

Note that the constant was denoted as $c^2$ to ensure positiveness. A similar solution holds for a negative constant, involving the hyperbolic tangent.

Comment: Why isn't it $\dfrac{1}{c^2}arctan(\dfrac{y}{c}) = x+c'$ Isnt $1/c^2$ a constant therefore you put it in front of the integral w/o changing it?

Comment: @aribaldi: check by differentiating.

Comment: Thanks, also I thinkthe final solution it's : $y=c\tan(c(x+c'))$

Comment: @aribaldi: $cc'\leftrightarrow c'$ makes no difference.

Answer (score -2):

Yeah. More generally if you have a 2nd degree nonlinear autonomous equation (no independent variable) do the following substitutions

y = y

y' = s

y'' = s*ds/dy

This reduces the order.